Can someone help me with this proof for the sum of the first n cubes?
I am trying to prove that
$\sum_{i=1}^n i^3 = \frac{n^2(n+1)^2}{4} = \frac{n^4+2n^3+n^2}{4}$.
I experimented by setting n = 5 and writing $1 + 8 + 27 + 64 + 125 = 1 + (1 + 7) + (1 + 7 + 19) + (1 + 7 + 19 + 37) + (1 + 7 + 19 + 37 + 61)$
We can rewrite this as $1 + (1 + (1 + 6)) + (1 + (1 + 6) + (1 + 6 + 12)) + (1 + (1 + 6) + (1 + 6 + 12) + (1 + 6 + 12 + 18)) + (1 + (1 + 6) + (1 + 6 + 12) + (1 + 6 + 12 + 18) + (1 + 6 + 12 + 18 + 24))$.
This is $\sum_{i=1}^5 i^3 = \sum_{i=1}^5 i + 6\sum_{i=1}^4 i + 12\sum_{i=1}^3 i + + 18\sum_{i=1}^2 i + 24$.
For any n, we write $\sum_{i=1}^n i^3 = \sum_{i=1}^n i + \sum_{i=1}^{n - 1}[6i\sum_{j=1}^{n - i}j]$.
Carrying out some summations, we get $\sum_{i=1}^n i^3 = \frac{n(n+1)}{2} + \sum_{i=1}^{n - 1}\frac{6i(n-i)(n-i+1)}{2}$.
Knowing that $i(n-i)(n-i+1)$ expands to $n^2i - ni^2 + ni - ni^2 + i^3 - i^2$, we write:
$\sum_{i=1}^n i^3 = \frac{n(n+1)}{2} + 3[(n^2 + n) \sum_{i=1}^{n - 1}i + (-2n -1)\sum_{i=1}^{n - 1}i^2 + \sum_{i=1}^{n - 1}i^3]$
We rewrite $\sum_{i=1}^{n - 1}i^3$ as $\sum_{i=1}^{n}i^3 - (n-1)^3$
Combining the $i^3$ summations and expanding, we get  $-2\sum_{i=1}^{n}i^3 = \frac{n(n+1)}{2} + 3(n^2 + n)\frac{(n-1)n}{2} + 3(-2n-1)\frac{(n-1)(n)(2n-1)}{6} - 3(n-1)^3$
This simplifies to $\sum_{i=1}^{n}i^3 = \frac{n^4+2n^3-17n^2+18n-6}{4}$, which is off from
our desired result of $\frac{n^4+2n^3+n^2}{4}$. Any thoughts would be appreciated. Thank you.

Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  How can you rewrite $\sum_{i=1}^{n - 1}i^3$ as $\sum_{i=1}^{n}i^3 - (n-1)^3$?

Ah I realize my mistake, thank you for the friendly and helpful reply!

Instead of rewriting $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n - 1}i^3$ as $\left(\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}i^3\right) - (n-1)^3,$
you should write $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n - 1}i^3$ as $\left(\sum
\limits_{i=1}^{n}i^3\right) - \color{red}n^3$,
and then you'll get the correct answer.

Here is a generalization of this.
If
$f_k(n) = \sum_{i=1}^n i^k$
($f_0(n) = n$)
then
$\begin{array}\\
f_k(n+1) 
&= \sum_{i=1}^{n+1} i^k\\
&= \sum_{i=0}^{n} (i+1)^k\\
&=1+ \sum_{i=1}^{n} (i+1)^k\\
&=1+ \sum_{i=1}^{n} \sum_{j=0}^k \binom{k}{j}i^j\\
&=1+  \sum_{j=0}^k \binom{k}{j}\sum_{i=1}^{n}i^j\\
&=1+  \sum_{j=0}^k \binom{k}{j}f_j(n)\\
\text{so}\\
(n+1)^k
&=f_{k}(n+1)-f_k(n)\\
&=1+  \sum_{j=0}^k \binom{k}{j}f_j(n)-f_k(n)\\
&=1+  \sum_{j=0}^{k-1} \binom{k}{j}f_j(n)\\
\end{array}
$
or
$kf_{k-1}(n)
=(n+1)^k-1-\sum_{j=0}^{k-2} \binom{k}{j}f_j(n)
$
or
$(k+1)f_{k}(n)
=(n+1)^{k+1}-1-\sum_{j=0}^{k-1} \binom{k+1}{j}f_j(n)
$
Examples:
If $k=1$
then
$\begin{array}\\
2f_{1}(n)
&=(n+1)^{2}-1-f_0(n)\\
&=n^2+2n+1-1-n\\
&=n^2+n\\
\end{array}
$
If $k=2$
then
$\begin{array}\\
3f_{2}(n)
&=(n+1)^{3}-1-f_0(n)-3f_1(n)\\
&=n^3+3n^2+3n+1-1-n-3(n^2+n)/2\\
&=\dfrac{2n^3+6n^2+6n+2-2-2n-3(n^2+n)}{2}\\
&=\dfrac{2n^3+3n^2+n}{2}\\
&=\dfrac{n(2n+1)(n+1)}{2}\\
\end{array}
$
If $k=3$
then
$\begin{array}\\
4f_{3}(n)
&=(n+1)^{4}-1-f_0(n)-4f_1(n)-6f_2(n)\\
&=n^4+4n^3+6n^2+4n+1-1-n-4\dfrac{n^2+n}{2}-6\dfrac{n(2n+1)(n+1)}{6}\\
&=n^4+4n^3+6n^2+3n-2(n^2+n)-(2n^3+3n^2+n)\\
&=n^4+2n^3+n^2\\
&=n^2(n^2+2n+1)\\
&=n^2(n+1)^2\\
\end{array}
$

There is a general method for summing the powers of $i$, which results from the properties of the binomial coefficients.
Indeed we have the formula $\displaystyle\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\binom{i}{k}=\binom{n+1}{k+1}\ $ see for instance this post.
Therefore instead of working in the power basis $1,n,n^2,n^3,\cdots$ you can advantageously work in the binomial basis $1,\binom{n}{1},\binom{n}{2},\binom{n}{3},\cdots$
So let's decompose $n^3$ in this basis !
$n^3-n(n-1)(n-2)=3n^2-2n\ $ and then $\,\,3n^2-2n=3n(n-1)+n$
Therefore $n^3=3!\binom{n}{3}+3\cdot 2!\binom{n}{2}+1!\binom{n}{1}=6\binom{n}{3}+6\binom{n}{2}+\binom{n}{1}$
It is then immediate that :
$\begin{align}\textstyle\sum i^3
&=\textstyle6\binom{n+1}{4}+6\binom{n+1}{3}+\binom{n+1}{2}\\
&=\textstyle\frac 6{24}(n+1)n(n-1)(n-2)+\frac 66(n+1)n(n-1)+\frac 12(n+1)n\\
&=\textstyle\frac 14(n+1)n\Big((n-1)(n-2)+4(n-1)+2\Big)\\
&=\textstyle\frac 14(n+1)n\Big(n^2+n\Big)\\
&=\textstyle\frac 14n^2(n+1)^2
\end{align}$
